# SQL Query Is The Join My Issue?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Include all records from table1 and only include records from table2 where the ID field is equal.

```
Select
Count(uno.itemID) As [Merchandise Sold],
uno.salesmanName As [Who Got Sale],
COUNT(duo.SalesCancelled) As [Bring it Back]
FROM table1 uno
INNER JOIN table2 duo
ON uno.itemID = duo.itemID
Group By uno.salesmanName
```

I have tried inner, right, left but am not getting expected outcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a `left join` because you say you want to keep everything in the first table:

```
Select Count(uno.itemID) As [Merchandise Sold],
       uno.salesmanName As [Who Got Sale],
       COUNT(duo.SalesCancelled) As [Bring it Back]
FROM table1 uno LEFT JOIN
     table2 duo
     ON uno.itemID = duo.itemID
Group By uno.salesmanName;
```